# How to create Apk extensions

Tags: android

I have an application that uses native libraries that supports **armeabi-v7a** and **x86**

I'm using Google Play multiple **apk** support feature to distribute two **apks**
but sometimes it detects the target device's **architecture** wrong and the **apk** with higher version code gets installed on the wrong architecture

Of course this is not the normal, but it's definitely not a small amount occurrence for us

So I want to implement something like **MXplayer**, it has a main application apk and other apks for supporting codex for different architectures

How can I support such behavior?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you saying google play detects wrong architecture? If so there's nothing you can do but raise the issue with google. Who's to know that the same devices don't have that problem when they download MXPlayer?

Comment: How much larger would a single APK be? If it's an acceptable amount larger to you, you can side step the issue.

Comment: Yes Google play detects the wrong architecture.

Comment: The APK size would be around 30 MB, I know it's not an issue but a major sector of our users in the developing countries with low internet connections and we want to make it as easy as possible for them to get the application, we had previous complains about the size

Comment: How much **larger** I asked? Have you considered expansion packs too, to distribute any assets that do not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the APK(s) at runtime. This is how plugins (i.e. themes, downloadable resources, etc...) are done.

```
/** Returns APK full path for application */
public static String getAPKPath(final Context context, final String appName)
        throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    return pm.getApplicationInfo(appName, 0).sourceDir;
}

/**
 * Returns a classloader that has APK loaded. APK must be installed.
 * @param context Android Context
 * @param app APK application full name
 * @return Classloader that has APK loaded
 */
public static ClassLoader loadAPK(final Context context, final String app)
        throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    final String apkPath = getAPKPath(context, app);
    final File tmpDir = context.getDir("tmp", 0);
    final DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(apkPath,
            tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, context.getClassLoader());
    return classLoader;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that?, some link or sample would be great :)

Comment: Would this code work for loading native libraries from other apks?

Comment: No, native libraries are not loaded using ClassLoaders, but a class on the APK can extract the native library somewhere and you can load it.